# Generic Interface in C# migrated from JAVA

Tags: c#

I want to convert this interface members to C#

```
<T> T GetValue(string areaKey, string key, Class<T> clazz);

<T> T GetValue(string areaKey, string key, T defaultValue, Class<T> clazz);
```

but I am not so good with C# as with JAVA. Is it possible to use it in the same way as in JAVA?

Comment: Is `Class<T>` something special in java? Im not that aware of Java syntax? IN c# that would imply you have a generic class called `Class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christos is correct, I would just add `where T : class`

```
public interface InterfaceName<T> where T : class
{
    T GetValue(string areaKey, string key, T clazz);
    T GetValue(string areaKey, string key, T defaultValue, T clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic type is just specified after the method name in C#

```
T GetValue<T> (string areaKey, string key, Class<T> clazz);
```

or, you can specify it on the interface itself:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T GetValue (string areaKey, string key, Class<T> clazz);
}
```

Comment: Hi, should we use Class<T>?

Comment: @Christos if you have a class called `Class` thats valid I guess. Would I ever name a class `Class`? probably not!

Comment: I got it. I got a bit confused with the `Class` and since I have no idea about JAVA, I didn't know if it is needed.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between those two approaches: the `T GetValue<T> ( ... )` is a generic method, while the `T GetValue ( ... )` in the `IMyInterface<T>` is a method of a generic interface. This matters if you had two methods. If the two methods were both just generic methods, they could both be used for different types for the same object, while if they're methods of a generic interface, they're restricted to both be the specific type of the interface.

Comment: If there's no particular reason any code outside the method body needs to know what specific type you use, it should probably be just a generic method.

Answer (score 1):

yup. You could try something like below:

```
public interface InterfaceName<T>
{
    T GetValue(string areaKey, string key, T clazz);
    T GetValue(string areaKey, string key, T defaultValue, T clazz);
}
```